# Toggle menu icons when submenu is opened/closed with jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a menu with icons that change when the menu open/closes. The problem is that when i click on a different menu, i want the previous icon to change back to it's closed state.

For example, you open a submenu and the caret-down changes to caret-up. You press that same menu and the caret is now caret-down. When you press another submenu i can't change this previous icon back to caret-down even if i can close the entire previous opened submenu.

Here is the code i'm working on:

```
toggleSubmenuIcon = function() {

var submenuIcons = $("a.dropdown-toggle > i"); //i element with the icon

//click the anchor
$("a.dropdown-toggle").click( function () {
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");
    closeIcons();
});
function closeIcons() {
    var icons = $("a.dropdown-toggle > i");
    var content = $("#menuMain > li.dropdown");

    icons.each(function () {
        if (!content.hasClass("open")) {
           $(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: `var content = $("#menuMain > li.dropdown");` is selecting **all** the dropdowns.  `!content.hasClass("open")` will only be true if **all** the dropdowns do not have the open class.  Ref. http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Also as a side note, `submenuIcons` and `icons` are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML markup looks something like this:

```
<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='#dropdown-1'><i class='fa fa-chevron-up'>Toggle 1</i></a>
<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='#dropdown-2'><i class='fa fa-chevron-up'>Toggle 2</i></a>
<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='#dropdown-3'><i class='fa fa-chevron-up'>Toggle 3</i></a>

<div class='dropdown' id='dropdown-1'>
  <div>Option 1</div>
  <div>Option 2</div>
  <div>Option 3</div>
</div>

<div class='dropdown' id='dropdown-2'>
  <div>Option 1</div>
  <div>Option 2</div>
  <div>Option 3</div>
</div>

<div class='dropdown' id='dropdown-3'>
  <div>Option 1</div>
  <div>Option 2</div>
  <div>Option 3</div>
</div>
```

You can just toggle the classes on the clicked `a`'s `i` child, then remove the `fa-chevron-down` class from the other `i` elements, and add the `fa-chevron-up` class. I just re-wrote it a little differently, but here's what I came up with (I added a `ShowDropdown` function, but you can tweak that to use whatever method you're already using to hide or show the corresponding dropdown).

```
var icons = $('a.dropdown-toggle > i');
var toggles = $('a.dropdown-toggle');

//function to show the corresponding dropdown when a toggle is clicked
function ShowDropdown(toggle) {
  //get the dropdown from the ID (assigned via data-toggle in the HTML)
  var dropdown = $(toggle.data('toggle'));
  //hide all other dropdowns - nothing will happen if they're already hidden
  $('.dropdown').not(dropdown).slideUp();
  //ensure dropdown is in correct location, and slide it down
  dropdown.css({
    left: toggle.offset().left,
    top: toggle.offset().top + toggle.outerHeight(true)
  }).slideDown();
}

//map the click event
toggles.click(function() {
  //find the current icon, and change its classes
  var icon = $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
  //remove the down class and add the up class to all others
  icons.not(icon).removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
  //if the dropdown is now selected...
  if(icon.hasClass('fa-chevron-down')) {
    //...show the dropdown...
    ShowDropdown($(this));
  }
  //...otherwise...
  else {
    //...hide the dropdown
    $($(this).data('toggle')).slideUp();
  }
});
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yakhodm/